# SMTP Connection over SSL TLS v1 giving timeout error

Tags: c#, email, ssl, smtp, tls1.2

I have to connect to the SMTP server of one our clients and that is over SSL using TLS v1
For this I have created a simple console POC using below code:

```
try
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient SmtpServer = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtpout.xyz.com");
    Console.WriteLine("sending mail...");
    mail.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("test@domain.com");
    mail.To.Add("test2@domain.com");
    mail.Subject = "TEST";
    mail.Body = "TEST DATA";
    SmtpServer.Port = 25;
    SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("", "");
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True;
    SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = False;
    SmtpServer.Send(mail);
    Console.WriteLine("mail sent successfully");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

But this is giving a very generic error that operation time out. When I am trying with a non-ssl smtp server over port 25 and no network credentials the mail is triggering immediately.

Please note, The client's SMTP server is reachable through a network load balancer not directly. I assumed that this issue can be due to improper handshaking between my machine and SMTP server so I also placed the certificate of SMTP server in my machine's trusted root certificate store but still problem exists.

What extra steps I have to take in configurations in this case of TLS 1.1/1.2 protocols. I have also tried a third party library for using STARTTLS command, but that also gives error which is "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or the established connection failed because the connected host has failed to respond".

Please suggest help.

Comment: Given that the third party library fails too it might be a problem on the server or load balancer end, i.e nothing you can solve at the client side. I recommend to try with other clients first and see if you even find one which works with the server setup. Once this is done you can figure out what the actual problem might be by comparing what working and non-working client do differently. Just hoping that switching to different TLS protocols will solve the problem is likely the wrong hope.

Comment: Thanks @SteffenUllrich , problem I am facing is I don't have any dummy smtp server with ssl to try this. Can you guide me if there is any dummy server online or it can be done only after purchasing a smtp server

Comment: If you want to test your code against SMTP servers doing TLS - most do. Try for example `gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com`. If you want to check if a normal client can speak SMTP with your specific server use a normal client, like Thunderbird etc.

Comment: Do I need to provide any network credentials ?

Comment: Thanks @SteffenUllrich I am able to connect with this smtp server, and in the wireshark logs I can see STARTTLS command being passed and handshaking is done on TLSv1.
But I observed that even in my code if I set the key as EnableSSL = False, then also I am able to send mail using this smtp server. What does it suggest.
Is it truly SMTP SSL server or not. And no certificate was required for handshaking but my client told that certificate is mandatory then how it connected without the use of certificate

Comment: The effect you describe is that TLS is optional (which is expected for this server) but that you can successfully use TLS. This suggests that the problem is not within your code but with the SMTP server of your client or the connection to this SMTP server (i.e. load balancer, deep inspection firewall etc). But as long as you are not able to connect to the clients SMTP server with some other program you cannot compare when a connection succeeds and when not. But this is needed to adjust your program to the servers requirements.

Comment: I didn't get this point clearly "But as long as you are not able to connect to the clients SMTP server with some other program you cannot compare when a connection succeeds and when not. But this is needed to adjust your program to the servers requirements." Do you mean I need to check configuration of any other application which is connecting properly with this SMTP server and then I need to do the changes in my code ?
I was also expecting the same that problem is with connection to this SMTP server (i.e. load balancer, deep inspection firewall etc).

Comment: Any role of client's SMTP server certificate can be here ? Though I have already kept that certificate on my machine's trusted root certificate store

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218429/discussion-between-steffen-ullrich-and-tanuj-shrivastava).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich
Does version of TLS also plays the role here. What if I am allowed to connect to SMTP server over particular TLS version for eg: over only TLS 1.2